# set value from filepicker to dialog that called it

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-creator

i have a action button that calls an dialog that i've made:

```
class MainPanelManager(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionLocation.triggered.connect(self.editsettings)

    def editsettings(self):
        dialog = QDialog()
        dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        dialog.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openfile)
        dialog.exec_()


    def openfile(self):
        folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Folder', 'C:/')
        # folder value must be set to dialog textedit
```

Dialog works and opens file picker when button is pressed. How to set the value when folder is selected. I need to put the value in `textedit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be declaring the `dialog` variable a property of `self` object. So, you can then use it class-widely in all methods.

```
class MainPanelManager(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionLocation.triggered.connect(self.editsettings)

    def editsettings(self):
        self.dialog = QDialog()
        self.dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.dialog.ui.setupUi(dialog)
        self.dialog.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openfile)
        self.dialog.exec_()


    def openfile(self):
        folder = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select Folder', 'C:/')
        # folder value must be set to dialog textedit
        self.dialog.ui.textedit.set_text(folder)
```